# complex Calculated Field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

we have what seems to be a complicated calculated column in our list, and are having trouble getting it to work

app_pr_apr01_status (calculated field)

```
If app_pr_action = "" and app_pr_apr01_action="" then app_pr_apr01_status="initial"
If app_pr_action = "submit" and app_pr_apr01_action="" then app_pr_apr01_status="pending"
If app_pr_action = "submit" and app_pr_apr01_action="approve" then app_pr_apr01_status="approved"
If app_pr_action = "submit" and app_pr_apr01_action="reject" then app_pr_apr01_status="rejected"
```

Tried Calculation but failed (HELP!!!)

```
=IF(
AND(app_pr_apr01_action="",app_pr_action=""),
    "initial",
    IF(
        AND(app_pr_apr01_action="",app_pr_action="submit"),
        "pending",
        IF(
            AND(app_pr_action="submit",app_pr_apr01_action="approve")
            ,"approved","rejected")
        )
    )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many closing parens:

```
=IF(AND(app_pr_apr01_action="",app_pr_action=""), "initial",
    IF(AND(app_pr_apr01_action="",app_pr_action="submit"), "pending",
       IF(AND(app_pr_action="submit",app_pr_apr01_action="approve"), "approved",
          "rejected")))
```

[image]

The easiest way to write and test these is to use Excel: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-creating-calculated-column.html

[image]